# PHP print to txt file from database and download the file, lines are messed up

Tags: php, mysql, download, export

I have 2 options, one to download all entries of a database; The second option to download only selected values (in a table, passed as array); both options download the entries in a file .txt one per line.

But, sometimes and only on certain lines, the result is messed up, and no new line is created.

Is there any idea on what could cause this?

That's the code for download:

```
            function DownloadAll() {
            //DOWNLOAD ALL DATAS
            $sql = $conn->prepare($query);
            $sql->bind_param('i', $userid);
            $sql->execute();
            $res = $sql->get_result();
            
            while ($ext = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
                $file = fopen('/home/tmp/'.$varr.'_export.txt', "a");
                if( strpos(file_get_contents('/home/tmp/'.$varr.'_export.txt'),$ext['account_name']) !== true) 
                {
                    $content = $ext['id'];
                    $content .= ":";
                    $content .= $ext['name'];
                    $content .= ":";
                    $content .= $ext['code'];
                    fwrite($file, $content);
                    fclose($file);
                } else { fclose($file); }
            }
            }

            function DownloadArray($data) {
            //DOWNLOAD FROM SELECTED ROWS ARRAY
            foreach($data as $do)
            {
                $sql = $conn->prepare($query);
                $sql->bind_param('ii', $userid, $do);
                $sql->execute();
                $sql->bind_result($id, $name, $code);
                $sql->fetch();
                $sql->close();

                $file = fopen('/home/tmp/'.$varr.'_export.txt', "a");
                if( strpos(file_get_contents('/home/tmp/'.$varr.'_export.txt'),$name) !== true) {
                    $content = $id;
                    $content .= ":";
                    $content .= $name;
                    $content .= ":";
                    $content .= $code;
                    fwrite($file, $content);
                    fclose($file);
                } else { fclose($file); }
            }
            }

            function export() {
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($varr.'_export.txt'));
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize('/home/tmp/'.$varr.'_export.txt'));
            readfile('/home/tmp/'.$varr.'_export.txt');
            sleep(1);
            unlink('/home/tmp/'.$varr.'_export.txt');
            die(); 
            }
```

And that is an example output (found in the .txt file) with the problem

```
1:vanne:tsvC2:rika:rgPrp3nierde:9K9g4:Caize:vW5g
5:lina:CZPr6:niki:phv47:hery:sh2u
8:shave:4xRj
9:riuster:S74W
10:bunn:vfH9
11:kei:t8vT
12:phas:R3kK
13:nelyn:Bw14:nedah:JtKu
15:rosi:Tfz4
16:seaur:mDY8
17:andrey:QSAA
18:taled:Tba519:evang:yedM20:taver:qs6n
```

As you see, some lines are all messed up, it doesn't create a new line and it just put the text right after the last one.

It doesn't happen randomly, only to specific lines with specific content or something, because if I download the same export multiple times, it won't be randomly messed up, all lines are messed up identically on all files.

EDIT

The problem was in the fwrite option not adding the new lines.

```
fwrite($file, $content.PHP_EOL);
```

Fixed it.

Comment: `fwrite()` doesn't append a newline to the data it writes. so I'd guess that the newlines you see must be part of the `$code` variable, and have come from the database, and therefore some `codes` don't have them. Check your data.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular You're right. I fixed it by editing fwrite($file, $content.PHP_EOL);

Answer (score 0):

[fwrite()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) is a binary-safe file write. It doesn't add a new line, and neither does your code.

The newlines you see must be coming from the data in your database.

Add a newline to each line:

```
fwrite($file, $content.PHP_EOL);
```

And ensure that your data doesn't have them.